# SQL: How to select a record where the value is lowest per unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am new to SQL and have been trawling around for an answer on this for the past few days but can't seem to find a definitive answer. (Or I am not understanding the solutions given as they don't match my scenario)

I have a table that resembles the below:

```
unique reference|tel number| tel priority
123|0123456910|2
123|0654321910|6
214|0056897910|4
```

I want to only output data where the priority of the tel number is the lowest for each unique reference, so in the above example I would want:

```
unique reference|tel number| tel priority
123|0123456910|2
214|0056897910|4
```

Any pointers/guidance is much appreciated, I have tried the MIN() functions but was unable to get it to do this as an output so I think I am missing something.

(I have SQL server 2008 r2 or Microsoft report builder)

Comment: Why does a column with the name "unique reference" have duplicates?

Comment: Hi Gordon, it's a table of contact details. So there are multiple tel numbers with the same unique identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the result you want:

```
SELECT * FROM phones WHERE tel_priority = (SELECT MIN(tel_priority) FROM phones p WHERE p.unique_reference = phones.unique_reference)
```

assuming `phones` is the name of the table.  
Of course if there are more than 1 rows containing the lowest value of `tel_priority` for a given `unique_reference`, then all these rows will be fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by uniquereference order by priority) as seq
      from table t
     )
where seq = 1;
```

If the `priority` has ties then use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple solution. i have tested and its working fine.if you like the answer then please vote

```
 select * from tablename where tel_priority not in(select max(tel_priority) from tablename)
```

Comment: This happens to work with the test data given, but it wouldn't work for a lot of other data. It only removes the single highest priority in the database, so if you had a record with id 214 and priority 3 (or anything other than 6) it would show both it's records. And if a reference only had records with the highest priority, it wouldn't show at all.